# How to navigate from MainActivity to (second) fragment using FAB button?

Tags: android, debugging, android-fragments, android-activity

I’m working on an Android project using the basic activity template. Android studio provides MainActivity and two fragments (and an additional contents_main layout). The **MainActivity layout has a floating action button** (FAB), and when the app starts, the first fragment is visible in the MainActivity. The first fragment layout also has a “next” button that navigates to the second fragment.

I want to **use the FAB button to navigate to the second fragment **(like next button). I tried using this (from another question) but the app crashes.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondFragment.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```

I also tried below solution searched by Bing (AI) to navigate to the second fragment, and it does work. However, when I **press **the **back button**, it takes me back to (blank) MainActivity and **first fragment is** somehow **removed**?, meaning its content is not there. And when I **click **the “**previous**” button in the second fragment, the **app crashes**.

```
binding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                
// Test fragment navigation              

    Fragment newFrag = new SecondFragment();

  // using fragment transaction to replace fragments.
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.layout_content_main, newFrag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
  }
});
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue? How can I navigate from the MainActivity to the second fragment using the FAB button without removing the first fragment?

*PS: I know i can just move the fab to fragment_first layout file, and then jsut copy the code from next button onclick listener in fab button on click listener, and it works, but i also want to learn the other way if it exists. TY.*

Comment: Are you using the Navigation Component? AFAIK the template you used has that dependency, but I'm not sure. Anyways, you should copy the code from the next button and use it in your fab button, because working with fragment transactions while using the navigation component at the same time is not a good idea, IMO. On the other hand, your first try with Intents doesn't work because they are meant to be used between activities. That's why it crashes when you pass your `SecondFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

You have passed `null` in the transaction `addToBackStack` so it will not keep your first fragment in the back stack while transacting from `FirstFragment` to `SecondFragment`.

To meet your requirement just change your code inside your fab button click method like below which adds the `FirstFragment` insider the back stack of the fragment transaction and when you click back button from `SecondFragment` it will open back stack fragment.

```
Fragment newFrag = new SecondFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.layout_content_main, newFrag);
// Here we are adding the first fragment in the back stack for the stack amagement
transaction.addToBackStack("FirstFragment");
transaction.commit();
```